# Comando LIKE e IN no mesmo comando SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

É possível utilizar `like` e `in` em um mesmo comando SQL? Por exemplo, preciso pesquisar na tabela **estoque** os Número de Série que podem ser `'SCAB171293E29','SCAB171293E4E'` porém pode ser que eles tenham algo a mais no fim por isso pensei em algo assim:

S`elect numeroserie from public.estoque where numeroserie like in ('SCAB171293E29%','SCAB171293E4E%')`

Porém obviamente deu erro. Existem algum modo de realizar esse `select`?

Comment: um `OR` não resolve o problema?

Comment: @rray Serão `n` números de séries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode ser informado um array contendo o início do número de série que deseja pesquisar conforme abaixo:

```
select *
from estoque
where numero_serie like any(array['SCAB171293E29%','SCAB171293E4E%']);
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu precisava, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa separar em 3 condições: `numeroserie`igual a 'SCAB171293E29' ou 'SCAB171293E4E', ou `numeroserie` parecido com 'SCAB171293E29%', ou número de série parecido com 'SCAB171293E4E%'. O resultado seria:

```
select numeroserie from public.estoque where numeroserie in ('SCAB171293E29','SCAB171293E4E') or numeroserie like 'SCAB171293E29%' or numeroserie like 'SCAB171293E4E%'.
```

Com verificações mais robustas é sempre interessante pensar de forma atômica para encontrar a solução final. Assim você pensa em cada critério de verificação separadamente e aí fica mais fácil juntá-los para a solução final.

Comment: O problema é que serão `n` números de série dai não tenho como colocar desse modo

Comment: Mas aí seria essa mesma solução adicionando as cláusulas OR. Você só precisa pensar numa ideia para construir a query, usando um programa Java, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim é exatamente o que faço na solução proposta pelo @CamiloSantos,  a única diferença entre as respostas de vocês foi a demora pra *query* terminar de executar, na ideia dele foi praticamente instantâneo já na sua ideia demorou bastante tempo até finalizar a *query*

Answer (score 0):

Bom se o tamanho do número de série é maior, não faz diferença alguma já que vc esta usando o % (afinal ele serve justamente para isso)
Talvez vc esteja se expressando mal, creio que sua dúvida seja, em alguns casos o seu in vai ter 3 números de série e em outros vai ter 15, por exemplo.
Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE numeroserie IN (SELECT NUMEROSERIE FROM OUTRA_TABELA)
```

Caso ainda não seja isso, vc deve então separar em varias clausulas. Por exemplo, quando o tamanho do numeroserie for 5 vc faz com o IN, quando for com 6, vc faz com o %.
Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE numeroserie IN ('numeroserie','numeroserie2') OR numeroserie like '%numeros%' OR numeroserie like '%serie'
```